# Swift UIScrollView can't change starting point of my slider

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiscrollview

I made this custom picker in SwiftUI but I can't figure out how to change the starting point to be 0,00 like in the picture attached:

[image: Desired outcome]

This is my code bellow

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomPicker: View {
@State var offset: CGFloat = 0

let integers: [Int]
let doubles: [String]

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            CustomSlider(sliderItems: integers.count, offset: $offset, content: {
                VStack(spacing: 0){
                    ForEach(integers, id: \.self ){ index in
                        
                        VStack {
                            Text("\(index)")
                                .font(.custom("Calibre", size: 65))
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .frame(maxWidth: 90, maxHeight: 90)
                        }.onTapGesture {
                            print("DEBUG: \(index)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            //maxHeight
            .frame(maxWidth: 90 , maxHeight: 270)
            Text(",")
                .font(.custom("Calibre", size: 65))
            
            CustomSlider(sliderItems: doubles.count, offset: $offset, content: {
                VStack(spacing: 0){
                    ForEach(doubles, id: \.self ){ index in
                        
                        VStack {
                            Text("\(index)")
                                .font(.custom("Calibre", size: 65))
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .frame(maxWidth: 90, maxHeight: 90)
                        }.onTapGesture {
                            print("DEBUG: \(index)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            //maxHeight
            .frame(maxWidth: 90 , maxHeight: 270)
        }
    }
}
}

func  getRect()-> CGRect{
   return UIScreen.main.bounds
}

struct CustomSlider<Content: View> : UIViewRepresentable {

var content: Content

//Binding offset for KG calculcations
@Binding var offset : CGFloat
var sliderItems: Int

init(sliderItems: Int, offset: Binding<CGFloat>,@ViewBuilder content: @escaping ()->Content){
    self.content = content()
    self._offset = offset
    self.sliderItems = sliderItems
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return CustomSlider.Coordinator(parent: self)
}

func makeUIView(context: Context) ->  UIScrollView {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let swiftUIView = UIHostingController(rootView: content).view!
    
    let height =  CGFloat(sliderItems * 90) + 180
    
    swiftUIView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: height)
    
    scrollView.contentSize = swiftUIView.frame.size
    scrollView.addSubview(swiftUIView)
    //scrolling is not magnetic
    scrollView.bounces = false
    //hide scroll indicator
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator
    
    return scrollView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
    
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate{
    var parent: CustomSlider
    
    init(parent: CustomSlider){
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView ){
        parent.offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let offset  = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let value = (offset / 90).rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)
        
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: value * 90), animated: false)
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        //if end decelarate not fired
        if !decelerate {
            let offset  = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            let value = (offset / 90).rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)
            
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: value * 90), animated: false)
        }
    }
   }
  }


 struct CustomPicker_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
      CustomPicker(integers: Array(-5...20), doubles: ["00", "25", "50", "75"])
   }
 }
```

I should be able to scroll from -5 to 20, start from 0,00 and have
only 3 values displayed vertically. Is this doable with my current approach ?
Note that I already tried using the SwiftUI built in Picker() but I can't customize it enough to fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding the bellow line to the makeUiView method solves the issue:

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: "the offset value goes here")
```